# unblock ip address after failed login attempts?

Tags: users

I have a custom login page that I'm testing the javascript on. The events I'm testing happen after a failed login.

After running a couple tests, I've managed to get my ip blocked because of numerous failed logins!

I have access to the database. How can I unblock my ip so I can continue to test my features without interruption?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I presume you are using Drupal 7. Did you check the {blocked_ips} table?

Comment: Nope, I hadn't :)